# Problems with DNS

Tags: networking, 16.04, google-chrome, dns

I am having issues with DNS. Regularly when I navigate to a page using Chrome, I receive the following error:

[image: Image showing DNS error]

This error is usually on the screen for a second or two before the page loads normally. This doesn't appear to happen when using Firefox.

I also appear to have DNS issues when installing/updating from the terminal, sometimes receiving the following message:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
```

But then if I rerun the same command immediately after receiving that message, the command executes without error.

These errors are intermittent and don't happen every time.

`Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit)`

`Kernel: 4.4.0-24-generic`

So far I've tried the following:

[How to Clear the Google Chrome DNS cache on Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/197804/how-to-clear-the-google-chrome-dns-cache-on-windows/)

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you just want to solve:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Comment out the line that says dns=dnsmasq

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Or if you want to know why, you could try investigating how your dns server behaves during the day, how it usuallly responds to a ping. Some providers or carriers want to save money and don't invest on overloaded DNS servers. If someone gave support to your computer, he could have changed the DNS server to his own custom DNS, then a fresh install is recommended. There are just too many options. You should try to specify more what happened.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. How can I specify more what happened?

Comment: What was unusual? How the problem started? Did you noticed the installation of anything, specially out of apt-get? Do you use your microwave oven next to your pc, things like that? Are you the only user who has root access? Do you use a firewall (at least ufw)? Are you rich enough for someone try to steal you? (please don't answer that)

Comment: There are ways of checking the uptime of provider or carrier server dns you should research to guarantee it is not only they're greed (poor hardware), or if they are suffering for DoS attacks. Basically if that's the case and you're on a serious country (not mine) you can sue your provider or carrier. They will quickly solve your problem.